# Can a bad battery cause random beachball and other crashes?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, crash, performance

I have a 2015 MacBook Pro exhibiting strange, seemingly random, beachball and application freezes. Sometimes so bad the machine has to be force shutdown.

On a recent hardware diagnostic test (hold D at startup) it reported an error on the battery. I'm wondering if the two are connected - the battery being out of spec causing the system to hang up from time to time.

The problem machine is running 10.11, and I'm updating it to 10.12 now to see if things get any better.

[edit]
The battery error was "PPT004: The battery requires service. The battery is not functioning normally, though you may not notice a change in its behavior or the amount of charge it holds. You can continue to use your battery before it’s checked without harming your computer."

Comment: Would you be able to update the question with the exact error code from Apple Diagnostics?

Comment: It's possible the battery could cause issues with RAM memory loss, which I would assume could cause a SWOD. The exact error would be helpful in determining if it is a factor.

Comment: Ditto on Jake3231's comment. Doing an Apple Diagnostics test will produce an error if you are not connected to a power supply or if your power supply is not the same wattage as the one your computer originally shipped with. An exact error code will help us a lot.

Comment: PPT004: The battery requires service. The battery is not functioning normally, though you may not notice a change in its behavior or the amount of charge it holds. You can continue to use your battery before it’s checked without harming your computer.